# Garageband menu like animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewanimation

In my application, I have navigation controller with two view controllers: MainController and DetailController.

In main view controller I have an image view and I want to push DetailController with animation like GarageBand menu when I tap on image view(look to 20 second of this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMRTvU17dMI&feature=player_detailpage#t=19s)).
So, question is how to implement fade-in animation.

Here's the code:

```
//calls on tapping on image
- (void)tapImageView:(UIImageView *)sender {
    DetailController *detailController = [[DetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"controller" bundle:nil];
    //configure detail controller 

    //here comes animation
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:NO];
    [detailController release];
}
```

I can animate image fading out:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
//sender is UIImageView
sender.frame = self.view.frame;
imageView.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but anytime I push my DetailViewController to navigationcontroller, that animation doesn't show.

How to implement GarageBand's menu switching animation?

Thanks.

Comment: You want fade in animation or slide in animation?

Comment: You want the same animation that garage band uses when the user tap on an instrument (with the loading, etc)?

Comment: I meant fade-in animation on tap on an instrument

Comment: It's an resize(enlarge) animation with fade-out... Simple.

Answer (score -1):

How about using paging with UIScrollView.

I think it is better than using UIView animation.